# Rcpp: NumericVector input and output change the original input data, but IntegerVector doesn't

Tags: r, rcpp

I am new to Rcpp and experimenting it at the moment. In a toy code, I tried to replace a even number in a vector by the number times 2.

In one case I used NumericVector as input and output data types, and in another case I used IntegerVector.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace std;
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector replaceEven(NumericVector x) {

  for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++) {
    if (fmod(x[i], 2) == 0) {
      x[i] = x[i] * 2;
    }
  }
  return x;
}

sourceCpp("RcppReplaceEven.cpp")
> y = c(1,2,3,4)
> replaceEven(y)
[1] 1 4 3 8
> y
[1] 1 4 3 8
```

However, after replacing NumericVector by IntegerVector, the result is

```
> y = c(1,2,3,4)
> replaceEven(y)
[1] 1 4 3 8
> y
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

Just wondering why this is the case.

Comment: That has been discussed a few times before. In one case you "cast" to another type which creates a copy -- no change to the incoming variable as it got copied. In the other case, because it internally comes as a pointer, gets change. Look at `clone()` for an alternative.

Comment: Where does cast come from?

Comment: No, it is your function `replaceEven()`.  Please look at some Rcpp answers here containing `clone()`.

Comment: In another case, it is IntegerVector replaceEven (IntegerVector x). Both input and outputs are IntegerVectors. Why is there a cast in this case? Thanks.

Comment: [This post](https://zenglix.github.io/Rcpp_basic/) might be useful, in particular the sub-section `NumericVector` in  section `Rcpp Data Structure`.

Comment: @Fred I talk about your problem in these 2 slides: https://privefl.github.io/R-presentation/Rcpp.html#29

Comment: I think I get it now. I forgot y=c(1,2,3,4) was actually a numeric vector. If using y=c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), then the result will be the one expected.